# why this command not work in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a JSFiddle, but I dont get the console to load.

http://jsfiddle.net/RPpXu/

```js
var dataList = $(".list").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("id");
}).get();

console.log(dataList.join("|"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <ul>
    <li class="list" data-id="123">One</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="124">Two</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="125">Three</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="126">Four</li>
</ul>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>form ajax</title>
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
 
      <script>
var dataList = $(".list").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("id");
}).get();

console.log(dataList.join("|"));
</script>
  
  
  
  
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="list" data-id="123">One</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="124">Two</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="125">Three</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="126">Four</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

please help me

Comment: Is the problem only to look at the console in JSFiddle??? If so, it [F12]! Or are you having an issue with this small script which seems to work ?

Comment: i post again is the last code not load console

Comment: is the last code not the first

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. I repeat, if you want to look at the console, using JSFiddle, press [F12] on your keyboard.

Comment: Your `console.log` works perfectly fine in your JSFiddle code.

Comment: Code in question won't work because the elements don't exist when you run the code. Wrap in `$(function(){ /* code here */})`. In jsfiddle this is done for you by the setting in javascript panel for *"Load Type"* which is default to *"onLoad"* and it works fine there